# Where the auto suggest results implemented in SXA?

Tags: sxa, content-search

I'm using Sitecore 9 update 1 with SXA 1.7, I configured the search box suggestion mode to be "ShowsPredictions", I know that the implementation is in `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.VersionSpecific.Services.SolrSuggester`, I override it and changed a little bit and it worked, but when I changed the suggestion mode to be "ShowSearchResultsAsPredictions" it didn't work well, it seems that the implementation is at different location.

Answer (score 1):

In the Search Box control properties you've three options for Suggestion Mode:

- Show search results - those are standard search results displayed as suggestions if you will click on one of them you will be redirected to that item
- Show predictions - those are the real suggestions which come from Solr suggester component
- Show search results as predictions - those are standard search results but without links to those certain items, when you will click on one of those it will be put in the Search Box input

I don't know what are you planning to modify and it might be harder for those two options besides *Show predictions* but more details you will find in `SearchController` and `GetSuggestions()` method.

Comment: Yes, in "Show predictions" mode I overrided GetSuggesions() which is in the SolrSuggester to return the template name of the item, but in "Show search results as predictions" I can't find its implementation, I want to know its class so I can override it.

Comment: LIke I mention above - `SearchController` and `GetSuggestions()` method. But it might be tricky (still possible) to override this controller and I wouldn't suggest that.

Comment: I overrided GetSuggestions() but it works only in "Show predictions" mode, at "Show search results as predictions" it don't work, when I debug the GetSuggestions() is not called, so I think it's implemented something else, I want to know the current implementation, If it's in the SearchController, can you tell me please which dll to recompile to find the exact implementation.