# search component- suggestion issue

Tags: sxa, content-search, sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

Working on Sitecore commerce 9 update 1.

Search-box is listing multilingual suggestions when typing.

I have an item with content in English and Chines version.
I have 2 issues to highlight,

1. When only English version is published, search result/suggestion will list english version content. But when English and Chines vesion is published, search result will only have Chinese version.
2. On further investigation I found that, when the AJAX call is made for search suggestion, context language is not set in query string.

[image]

And also, when AJAX call is made from search result page context language is set ( because this page have a rendering where we can set the language filter).

[image]

Anyone worked on sitecore 9 SXA search component and came across this ?

Is there any way we can easily setup language filter in search component without customizing the OOTB module ?

Comment: I did have the same issue on a SXA site (no commerce) that the search suggestions were based on the current language..  As Support could not give me a patch, I disabled the suggestions. I would open a ticket with Sitecore Support and hope they have a fix now.

Comment: I suggest to customise the search-box.js where query suggestion url is building.append the language based on current context language if language parameter is empty.

Comment: So, for a quick fix we can edit search-box.js and then raise a ticket with Sitecore support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's clarify a few things. The Solr Suggester component doesn't support language at all. For more details please take a look here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/suggester.html

In SXA you have few options to receive suggestions as I described here: [Where the auto suggest results implemented in SXA?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/15354/where-the-auto-suggest-results-implemented-in-sxa).

Now, knowing about two above I'm assuming that you are not using real Solr suggestions but one of two other options which in fact are just showing search results as suggestions/predictions. I've just checked the last code (just code check without debugging) and as far as I can see the language is pass to `createSuggestionsUrl()` function in the `component-search-box.js`. Take a look here:

[image]

**UPDATE - 03-01-2018**

If you would like to pass language to the suggestion request please update `Default langue filtering` option in the Control Properties of the Search Box rendering. Take a look here:

[image]

If you will choose Current Language than `inst.getLanguage()` will return proper language.

Comment: We are using Azure search. The inst.getLanguuage() is getting empty when we have added SXA searchbox component in non SxA pages. I assume that language value is getting from Search result component from the current context language parameter. Here we have added only Search box component. As a result , language value is not getting the proper value.

Comment: @Dawid, I have searchbox on all pages. And I found that inst.getLanguuage() is set only when I do search from search-result page.

Comment: @Jijo and Hussain I'll check that for you guys tomorrow when I'll be on front of the PC.

Comment: @JijoViswanathan I've updated my question.

Comment: @Hussain I've updated my question. Take a look at `Default langue filtering` dropdown in the Search Box parameters.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski, by default {search box} rendering parameter doesn't have DefaultLanguageFilter field, but {search results} rendering parameter have it. Anyway your findings were right. Thanks for the reply.